# Installing wget for Mac

Tags: vim, wget

I was installing wget 1.13 after downloading it from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/.
I followed the instructions laid here http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/howto-install-wget-for-mac-os-x/.
A problem arose when I was running ./configure.
The output I received in the terminal was

```
error: --with-ssl was given, but GNUTLS is not available
```

Hence, I was unable to carry on to

```
make
make install
```

Anyone who has an idea what i am missing here?

All assistance are greatly appreciated.

I'm running on Mac 10.7.3, if it helps.

Thank you.

Comment: That's not a programming question. Maybe one for superuser.com

Answer (score 16):

I would suggest using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

It's a very simple and easy install and once it's done, you can just type `brew install wget` and it does everything automatically for you.